# Python - why its not able to find the window title?

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, chromium

I have following code and its unable to activate the window title "Stack Overflow" and sending the f11 to wrong GUI.

Is this a Python bug? Why its not working?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import win32com.client as comctl
import time

def chromes():
  url='https://stackoverflow.com'
  cmd='C:/Users/tpt/AppData/Local/Chromium/Application/chrome.exe'
  Popen([cmd, url, '--window-position=0,0', '--user-data-dir=C:\\iplay'])

chromes()
time.sleep(5)

wsh =comctl.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
aa = wsh.AppActivate("Stack Overflow")
wsh.SendKeys("{F11}")
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No ERROR. also tried: `from pywinauto.findwindows    import find_window
from pywinauto.win32functions import SetForegroundWindow
SetForegroundWindow(find_window(title='Stack Overflow - Chromium'))`

Comment: youre sure the page loaded within those 5 seconds of sleep?

Comment: YEA - those 5 seconds of sleep was perfect. What is not working is this line "aa = wsh.AppActivate("Stack Overflow")" and this line "SetForegroundWindow(find_window(title='Stack Overflow - Chromium'))" can you please keep testing and make sure it works. cause there are tons of answer but when you tried them none works anymore in windows 8 and windows 10

Comment: interesting `tab name` is `windows name` ? Which tab stay front , your application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'Stack Overflow' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F11, 0)


win32gui.EnumWindows(enumHandler, None)
```

But no idea about which tab effected ?